# .doc в web-разработке

Tags: веб-программирование, ms-word

Доброго времени суток!

Появилась задача в автоматическом создании и заполнении договоров, поискав информацию в интернете нашел только PhpOffice и все. 
Подскажите каким образом можно создавать и заполнять word документы.

Comment: сделай пдф форму)

Comment: Если вы хотите писать под php - то так и пишите в вопросе об этом, а лучше в гугле вбиваете библиотека ворд для пхп. Если хотите что-то свое городить - само проще - rtf. Rtf формат довольно хорошо документирован, и довольно хорошо терпит вставки, потому что он текстовый. doc и docx довольно сложные форматы, нужно или писать самому довольно крупную либу и бороться с кучей багов, либо проще найти бесплатную хоть и не полнофункциональную, но приемлимую по функциональности.

Comment: @nick_n_a огромное спасибо! Разобраться в использовании действительно просто, но главное все работает, хоть и с парой НО.